# Foundation Off-Canvas-Menu covers entire screen

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation CSS framework create and off-canvas-menu, however, when I click the off-canvas-toggle anchor, the menu slides in and covers the entire screen.  I am unable to get out of the menu.  The example on the foundation page (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html) doesn't have this problem.  Am I doing something wrong/missing something?

```
<div class="fill-h off-canvas-wrap move-right">
<div class='fill-h inner-wrap'>
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        Left off canvas menu
    </aside>

    <div class="row fill-h">
        <div class="xlarge-2 large-3 medium-1 columns show-for-medium-up fill-h" id="a">
            <div class='row' id='navTabs'>
                <a href="#/ic"><div class='small-4 columns active'><img src='/img/icon.png' /><br/>Current</div></a>
                <a href="#/in"><div class='small-4 columns'><img src='/img/icon.png' /><br/>New</div></a>
                <a href="#/ip"><div class='small-4 columns'><img src='/img/icon.png' /><br/>Phone</div></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navListing" ui-view="vw-listing">

            </div>

            <div id='nav_footer' class='small-12'>
                <div id="adminMenuBtn">
                    Admin
                </div>
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="xlarge-10 large-9 medium-11 columns" ui-view="vw-details2">
            <div style='background-color:#333;float:left;'>
                <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div ng-include="views/interactions/details-blank.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>        
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have run your code and do not get this problem. You must have some conflicting css somewhere?

Comment: I think you're probably right.  We have opted to move away from Foundation, so it's no longer an issue for us.